# How can I changle language of build errors in VS 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I recently got a new workstation where I'm using Visual Studio 2008 Professional for mainly C# development. At my previous workstation all build errors were presented in english, which I strongly prefer. However, at this new workstation all build errors (and exceptions) are in my native language. I find this very annoying. Do anyone know how I can make all my build errors and exception be presented in english instead? Do I need to re-install the .NET framework for this to happen?

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to set the language of the IDE from the Options-Dialog, Environment -> International Settings. Though, English needs to be installed to do so...I haven't seen an option to chooses different language settings in the setup of Visual Studio, so you may get a hold of an english copy and reinstall it.

Comment: I tried changing the international settings in the options menu. Didnt help thoe...

Answer (score 0):

After further research into this problem it turns out that the expection messages will be in the same language as your installed operating systems language, independently of what system language is set in Visual Studio or in Regional Settings in the Control Panel. So the only solution is to re-install the operating system with an english version.

However stupid this might be, it turns out to be the case.